# How to Apply Data Labels to a chart using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply data labels to my chart using VBA.

I run into

> run-time error 'ApplyDataLabels' of object 'Series' failed.

This is the code

```
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
```

and cht is

```
cht = ChtObj.Chart
```

I also tried

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ApplyDataLabels
```

However the code skips over that line like it is not there.

Comment: `FullSeriesCollection` includes series that are filtered out - is that the case for your chart?

Comment: No, so I have the top 10 filtered for the chart

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but try `SeriesCollection` instead of `FullSeriesCollection`.

Comment: The chart is a pivot chart and I have the chart filtered to show the top 10 values.

SeriesCollection doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
```